# How can I disable smooth scrolling in Adobe Reader 9?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, scrolling

Smooth scrolling makes me dizzy and reduce battery life :)

I'm using Adobe Reader 9.1.1 under Windows Vista SP1 and I cannot find the option...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Navigate to **Edit -> Preferences**
- Select **Page Display** in the Categories pane.
- In the **Page Content And Information** section, uncheck the **Use Smooth Zooming** checkbox.
- Click OK.

[image]

This will also fix jerky scrolling. I believe they removed the **use smooth scrolling** checkbox in version 9 and included the scrolling into the zooming checkbox.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Sorry about the mixup. It appears adobe has incorporated the two features into **smooth zooming**.